# Getting the error 'Event handler '' not found on class '' '

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am building a Windows Phone application and i am trying to get my app to connect to twitter. I have set up a page where the user is required to authorize the app's use of their twitter account. However whenever i try to run my program i get the following error:

Error   1   Event handler 'loginBrowserControl_Navigated' not found on class 'TheSocialHub.TwitterSetup'    C:\Users\charlie stuart\Desktop\Windows Phone Project\TheSocialHub\TheSocialHub\TwitterSetup.xaml   TheSocialHub

Below is the code i am using,

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="TheSocialHub.TwitterSetup"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Sample twitter app" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="main page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <Grid x:Name="TweetPanel" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserName" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Segoe WP Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        </Grid>


        <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="LoginBrowserControl" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="473" Width="436" Visibility="Collapsed"
                          Navigated="loginBrowserControl_Navigated" Navigating="loginBrowserControl_Navigating"/>

    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

VB.NET code for the page:

```
Imports Hammock.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports Hammock
Imports System.Text
Imports Hammock.Authentication.OAuth

Partial Public Class TwitterSetup
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

Dim OAuthTokenKey As String = String.Empty
Dim tokenSecret As String = String.Empty
Dim accessToken As String = String.Empty
Dim accessTokenSecret As String = String.Empty
Dim userID As String = String.Empty
Dim userScreenName As String = String.Empty


Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    If isAlreadyLoggedIn() Then
        userLoggedIn()
    End If
End Sub

Private Function isAlreadyLoggedIn() As [Boolean]
    accessToken = MainUtil.MainUtil.GetKeyValue(Of String)("AccessToken")
    accessTokenSecret = MainUtil.MainUtil.GetKeyValue(Of String)("AccessTokenSecret")
    userScreenName = MainUtil.MainUtil.GetKeyValue(Of String)("ScreenName")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessTokenSecret) Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub userLoggedIn() Handles loginBrowserControl.Navigated, loginBrowserControl.Navigating
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Function()
                               Dim SignInMenuItem = DirectCast(Me.ApplicationBar.MenuItems(0), Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMenuItem)
                               SignInMenuItem.IsEnabled = False

                               Dim SignOutMenuItem = DirectCast(Me.ApplicationBar.MenuItems(1), Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarMenuItem)
                               SignOutMenuItem.IsEnabled = True

                               TweetPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
                               txtUserName.Text = "Welcome " & userScreenName

                           End Function)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You need to have a loginBrowserControl_Navigated method in your code-behind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the declaration of events in your VB.NET code file

Just add these declarations in your code and check

```
Private Sub loginBrowserControl_Navigating(sender As Object, e As NavigatingEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub loginBrowserControl_Navigated(sender As Object, e As NavigationEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: But i already have Private Sub userLoggedIn() Handles LoginBrowserControl.Navigated, LoginBrowserControl.Navigating in my code?

Comment: check with replacing the previous code with what I have given.